# Is a T1 sufficient for 12 Pcs

Tags: bandwidth, t1

The company I work for is in an area where only T1 s are available.  We have 12 PCs Networked, I guess is the terminology and the company promised us 1.59 MBP, I have checked download speeds on all 12 pcs NOT ONE is getting more than 700Kbps ...  The company says we are using all our band width and that is why none of the pcs are getting any mbp.
Would this be true...  We do not do a lot of down loading.  Mostly our own Point of sale and some searches. Any info is appreciated

Comment: Knowing how your network is configured will go a very long way to answering this question; for example if you are connecting all 12 to a full duplex switch, passive hubs, if one is running a web server...etc.  Knowing that information will let us fully understand how your setup is working.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the T1 is sufficient, or not is dependent upon what the PCs are using the internet for. For basic things like surfing the internet, without much streaming, and checking email, it is probably fine. Given what you said about use, a T1 should be sufficient.

You should definitely speak to your ISP about the speeds you are receiving. You're getting about half of what you are paying for. A T1 is a dedicated line. You should be seeing nearly all of your bandwidth, period.

T1s typically come with detailed SLAs. Check their site for the SLA(Service Level Agreement) for their T1s. You might be entitled to money back. If they are a decent provider, their SLA will cover service speed and they will credit your bill if they aren't meeting the requirements of the SLA. You might as well check for things like latency, packet loss, etc. too. These are all areas that should be touched on in the SLA.

Answer (score 0):

With a full T1, you should see download speeds of 1.4Mbps or so on sites like [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net). You should see peak download speeds of about 160KB/s. Test when your network is lightly loaded. If possible, turn every computer off but the one you're using.

If you literally never see speeds over 700Kbps from speed testing sites and never see download speeds over 100KB/s, I'd suspect something is wrong with your T1. Perhaps it's not a full T1, or perhaps it's misconfigured somehow.

Do you have access to the device on your end that the T1 connects to? You can probably learn a lot from its statistics and monitoring information.

T1s may be slow, but unless they're broken, they should be very, very near 100% -- at least to whatever device is on the other end of the T1. Your local network would have to be pretty badly broken (like a duplex mismatch, or the worst WiFi imaginable) for it to degrade your T1's performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Is a T1 sufficient for 12 Pcs?**  It depends on your needs.

1. If your users are just using it for email and web browsing it should
   be fine.
2. If you're planning to stream audio/video or serve websites
   from it then no.

**The company I work for is in an area where only T1 s are available**

See if there are any wireless network providers in the area.  If there are you may get 10x the bandwidth of T1. If not, you might consider a point to point link to somewhere that has faster access.